# Unable to mark pendrive as active

Tags: usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

Unable to make my Usb-flash-drive Active.I have used the dos command but nothing fruitfull happend what should i do.I can not clean it though clean command using DOS.

Comment: What do you mean by active? You say you have used 'the dos command'? What does that mean? Please elaborate *much*.

Comment: @user333122 Make sure the USB flash drive is formatted as NTFS file system and try to set as active.

Comment: Why would you all down vote this question?  He asked a legit question.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Diskpart to accomplish this?
 Open up cmd and type in `Diskpart` and it'll allow you to access those tools. From there:

`list disk` - shows all disks and their number
`select disk X` - selects disk number X
`list partition` - shows all partitions on that disk and their number
`select partition X` - selects partition number X
`active` - sets selected partition as active

So you basically need to use these commands to locate your flash drive's disk, then select whatever partition you would like to set active for your flash drive, then issue the active command

At the time of posting this answer your question isn't very clear, so I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use diskpart.exe, or diskmgmt.msc (or compmgmt.msc for that matter) some flash will not allow you to set a Primary Partition as 'Active'. For me this always goes hand in hand with a drive that cannot be formatted as NTFS, but only FAT (though you can reformat it as NTFS, after initially formatting as FAT).

My personal fix for it is to use Rufus, and flash the ISO file directly (can also flash disk images taken with dd from '.img', or similar or disk images). You may also have luck with:

- Yumi
- UNetBootIn
- Win32DiskImager
- live usb creator

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late but the solution i found was to run 'convert MBR' before the format or after the clean command.

Comment: how does this answer the question?